# How to upload the WordPress theme zip file to prestashop?

Tags: wordpress, upload, zip, themes, prestashop

I have export the WordPress theme to zip file and now I am trying to upload the zip file to PrestaShop

I need to use the WordPress theme in the prestashop, How can I upload the WordPress theme into prestashop theme?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prestashop is not WordPress so you can't upload a WordPress theme to Prestashop. The work needed to adapt your theme to Prestashop will be too big so it is preferable to take another theme that is compatible with Prestashop.